# Avoid redundancy of version in yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

Is it possible to remove redundancy when dumping multiple config in same yaml file

```
import yaml
with open('r.yaml', 'w') as r:
    a = [{'len' : 5, 'weidth' : 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
    yaml.dump_all(a, r, version=(1,2))
```

And expected output

```
%YAML 1.2
---
len: 5
weidth: 3
---
a: 2
b: 4
```

Currently it is

```
%YAML 1.2
---
len: 5
weidth: 3
%YAML 1.2
---
a: 2
b: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since YAML has been designed so that streams can easily be concatenated, you can just do

```py
import yaml,sys
with open('r.yaml', 'w') as r:
    a = [{'len' : 5, 'weidth' : 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
    for i,d in enumerate(a):
        version = (1,2) if i == 0 else None
        yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout, version=version, explicit_start=True)
```

You may want to open an issue with PyYAML since your original output is not valid YAML at all and PyYAML must produce `...` in front of `%YAML 1.2`.